# Is there an inconsistency in notability requirements?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

I have observed in the past moderators closing the question because it is not notable enough, specifically posted on blog/social media that doesn't show much viewership.

However, others seem to be considered perfectly OK. Recent example:

[Was Walt Disney a Freemason?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28341/was-walt-disney-a-freemason)

The claim is sourced in a blog that, at first glance, strikes me as not quite notable or believed by tons of people.

What exactly is the rule for showing notability, in quantifiable terms?

To clarify: I'm **not** asking how the side decides notability (by having a moderating users VTC, duh). I'm asking **what are the qualitative rules** that a moderating user is supposed to use as a guideline for yes/no call on whether to close as non-notable.

Side question: Are those rules enforced consistently?

Comment: there are 43 links to the page from Google search, some or even most seem to be SEO scrapers at first glance.

Comment: Side answer: there is no need for them to be enforced consistently, only that this works "well enough".

Answer (score 3):

The general notability standard is whether many people believe the claim.

As a person with the privilege of voting to close or re-open, how are you to judge that?

It is judged as a matter of first impression, and we are encouraged to do some work to try to determine if a claim may be notable before voting to close.

Admittedly, "many" is vague, but it seems to me that most people that have gained the experience needed to earn the vote-to-close privilege have learned to interpret that word fairly consistently.

Also, as far as I can tell, this site hasn't established any *per se* rules that would make a claim notable or non-notable if it were found on site X or said by person Y. Each claim is assessed case-by-case.

Some cues that the community has looked to include:

- [Number of shares on Twitter or Facebook, etc.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2324/25668)
- [Popularity of the speaker](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/what-is-minimum-notability-of-claims-for-this-site#comment6669_2322)
- [Prominence of the claim in a public space](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16007/is-the-value-of-a-tree-193-250)
- [The claim originating in a work of fiction](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies)
- [The claim being made by a traditional media source](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/is-asking-a-question-on-if-a-popular-news-story-correctly-conveys-a-new-study-on)
- [Number of websites repeating the claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2323/25668)
- [Whether the claim was made in earnest or as a joke](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/is-humor-and-satire-acceptable-for-notable-claims)

These (and many other claim-specific factors), taken together, inform my vote as to whether a claim is notable or not. If I'm on the fence, I give notability the benefit of the doubt.